# Changing the $from email in D6 contact_mail_user_submit()

Tags: 6, emails

```
// Send the e-mail in the requested user language.
  drupal_mail('contact', 'user_mail', $to, user_preferred_language($account), $values, $**from**);
```

I wish to change the `$from` email to `"do-not-reply@domain.com"` to accommodate our email configuration.

`$from` is defined as `$user->mail [here in the function][1]` and I can't figure out how to override this via `MODULE_form_contact_mail_user_alter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_mail_alter/6) to do that, e.g.:

```
function MYMODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'contact_user_mail') {
    $message['from'] = 'do-not-reply@domain.com';
  }
}
```

Comment: You put me on the right track.  thanks! This is actually what worked, though.

`$message['from'] = $message['headers']['From'] = 'do-not-reply@domain.com'; `